# Visual Leak Detector doesn't work for DLL projects' detection

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have many projects in my solution. Some of them are dll project. I had added `#include "vld.h"` into the "`stdafx.h`" file which will be included in all files. And I just wrote `char* t = new char[100];` on the line which will be executed when I started the application. But the VLD doesn't work. The output window just display there is no leak. But when I put `#include "vld.h"` in a static project, it worked! I don't know why, and how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should have read the instuctions:

https://vld.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Visual%20Leak%20Detector&referringTitle=Documentation

To use VLD with your project, follow these simple steps:

1. In at least one C/C++ **source** **(not header)** file from your program, include the vld.h header file. It should not matter which file you add the include statement to. It also should not matter in what order the header is included in relation to other headers. The only exception is stdafx.h (or any other precompiled header). **A precompiled header, such as stdafx.h, must always be the first header included in a source file, so vld.h must be included after any precompiled headers.**
2. If your program contains one or more DLLs that you would also like to check for memory leaks, then also include vld.h in at least one source file from each DLL to be included in leak detection.
3. Build the debug version of your program.

Comment: I  did as the instructions, but when I added the vld.h header file into the DLL, it didn't work.

Comment: You wrote "I had added #include "vld.h" into the "stdafx.h" file which will be included in all files" - it proves that you didn't read the instuctions. You should put "vld.h" in one of your source files AFTER you include "stdafx.h".

Comment: I found somewhere said with vld version2.3 you can put the #include "vld.h"  into a header file which will be included in all files. And it worked for the exe but not for DLL in my solution.